# Full Calender not displaying event in same order as given in json

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

I am using full calenderwith core php.html,javascript...and implementing my application on the linux server (cent os)and accessing from other window pc my full calender is not displaying the event in same order as in the given json (say suppose i m givign event1 , event 2, event 3 for all dates in a month ; i.e for each date there is 3 event in order 1, 2, 3 ..)rest all works well pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be check data format of start and end of full calendar event.
You should be try datetime in Unix timestamp or ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") .

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/